# Deserialize in a list from JSON to VB.NET

Tags: json, vb.net, parsing, webrequest

I Work with HTTPrequest and I [receive a response](http://textup.fr/140888sO) of a group of array in json. 
I want to parse it in VB.NET in a list to access at that:

```
List.index(0).messages.id
List.index(0).messages.previous
List.index(0).messages.last_update
List.index(0).messages.html
```

Thank for your help, I hope you understand my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting the json as an Array, why not deserialize it into Array only? And then you can use the `.ToList()` method to convert the array into a `List`.

Your classes should be like:

```
public class Message
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int previous { get; set; }
    public int last_update { get; set; }
    public string html { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string robots { get; set; }
    public List<Message> messages { get; set; }
    public List<int> messageIds { get; set; }
    public string onlineUsers { get; set; }
    public string reverse { get; set; }
    public int lastrefresh { get; set; }
    public string motd { get; set; }
    public int numInChat { get; set; }
    public bool twelveHour { get; set; }
    public string _visitor_conversationsUnread { get; set; }
    public string _visitor_alertsUnread { get; set; }
}
```

And you should be able to Deserialize your full jSon into the `RootObject` class directly. To deserialize, i will suggest Newtonsoft.Json dll(available at Nuget)

`RootObject rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);`

Then you will be able to access the properties as you asked.

*I took help of http://json2csharp.com/ to generate the classes from your jSon*

Comment: Thank, it's a good answer, but i already fix my problem myself, i just did your answer,